# Marathon-LB configuration on docker failed

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, mesos, marathon, mesosphere

I am creating marathon LB configuration on docker. I build the image from this dockerfile:

https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb/blob/master/Dockerfile

But unable to execute the docker run command:

> root@ip-10-1-0-251:~# docker run -e PORTS=9090 rk sse --group external
>
> [FATAL tini (5)] exec /marathon-lb/run failed: No such file or
>   directory

Comment: the image already exists on dockerhub https://hub.docker.com/r/mesosphere/marathon-lb/. You can use that.

Comment: but can you tell me the exact command to run this with docker run once i pull the image

Comment: `docker run -e PORTS=9090 mesosphere/marathon-lb sse`

Comment: 2017-09-26 11:58:36,466 marathon_lb: SSE Active, trying fetch events from http://master.mesos:8080/v2/events                                                         pycurl.error: (6, 'Could not resolve host: master.mesos')

Comment: @RohanKhanolkar can you add some more details about your environment? (the versions of Mesos, marathon, etc.)? It looks like marathon-lb might be running but can't find your Mesos Master?